# Play Asset Delivery - really limited to 50 asset packs?

Tags: android

I want to use Play Asset Delivery with my app. It's got 125 optional data files, each with an average size of about 2.8Mb. A user may only need a couple of these. PAD states there's a limit of 50 asset packs per app. Ideally I'd like to have one asset pack per data file, since they're independent of each other. I guess I could group them (rather arbitrarily) for the purpose of PAD to get under the limit of 50.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there another way to do this that better supports delivering 125 different assets?

Comment: Update: I added 42 asset packs containing my 125 assets, grouped somewhat arbitrarily. When I build the bundle, it only contains 18 packs. And the ones included seem quite arbitrary. wtf?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out, although it points to a bug (imho). The names I chose for my 42 asset packs were "languages1, languages2, ... languages42". If I change that to "languages01, languages02, ... languages42" it works.